# RN Web, href in TouchableOpacity: onPress >navigation, onRight click > context menu with possibility to open link

Tags: react-native-web

I have a site with TouchableOpacity that uses react-navigation to navigate to another screen. Is it possible in some way to add href to this button so I could open the another screen in new tab using context menu "Open link in new tab"?

I know there is possibility to add `accessibilityRole='link' href={''}` to a  component but what about a whole button of view.
This is according to: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/162

Using Text component it is possible by:

```
 <Text
   accessibilityRole='link'
   href={defineRightClick()}
   target='_blank'
   onPress={(e) => { 
     e.preventDefault();
     navigateFunction();
   }}>
     Click to navigate, right click to open in new tab
 </Text>
```

Ask if more information is needed for this question and I will edit it.
Every help is appreciated as I have tried to find solution but have not come across or found a way to handle this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer!

Even thought it is not documented in here: https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/accessibility/#accessibility-patterns
and using href in TouchableOpacity will show ts error `No overload matches this call.`, it is possible to add to a TouchableOpacity props

```
accessibilityRole='link'  
href={'desired link'}  
target='_blank'
```

Then using `e.preventDefault()` in onPress event of TouchableOpacity will prevent link opening and do other things assigned to the function. At the same time the link is possible to be opened with right click > context menu > "Open link in new tab"

I will post this as answer so if anyone else comes across this they might find the solution